# Content Query Web Part additional filters

Tags: web-part, content-query-web-part

I've been working on a SharePoint intranet implementation and have been trying to use the CQWP to aggregate a number of announcement lists throughout our site on the homepage. I've been using the additional filters options to try and filter out certain lists that I dont want to appear, such as those that appear on the same page, however after making the changes the web part displays:

This query has returned no items. To configure the query for this Web Part, open the tool pane.

I've tried filtering by both the name and also the List ID. I use no custom fields in any lists and an example of the query I've been using is below:

List ID > Contains > {40F0922F-A058-4950-B769-0711932FB071} I have also tried the Is not equal to modifier.

If anyone could give me any help on structuring an additional filter and making it work it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're rolling up content from Announcement lists from throughout many webs in your site collection this can be done with a Data View Web Part. There are at least a couple of tutorials on this over on EndUserSharePoint.com

Answer (score 0):

It's [now] a known bug in 2010 - below is e-mail I received from MS:

Further to our discussion had in the last week of March I had since then forwarded all our observations from our lab where we had successfully reproduced the issue, to our escalation team.

Accordingly a detailed analysis of those findings and a counter check was conducted by them to verify that the issue was indeed reproducible in all environments. At the end of this I have received a confirmation yesterday that the said issue with the FILTER does actually show up in the OOB setups as well.

Hence the escalation team has accordingly recorded this as a known issue / bug and appropriately filed it in the Microsoft internal bug database for further investigation and follow-up from the Product Group.

As a result I have to notify you that all troubleshooting action would henceforth cease as there is no solution/workaround that we can provide at this point in time for the issue. I would therefore request your permission to close this case as “UNRESOLVED – KNOWN ISSUE” and also issue the REFUND for the case incident.

Do let me know of your feedback so that we can proceed with the further action.

Thank you once again for your valuable contribution, inputs and tremendous patience demonstrated all across the span of this case.

Regards,

Parag Murudkar 
Support Engineer|Microsoft SharePoint Support